# 18.10 Getting "Package sgml-base is not configured yet." when running apt-get -f install as root

Tags: upgrade, dependencies, 18.10

Upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10 failed because of sgml-base dependency error, but was able to continue

I tried re-installing `sgml-base` 1.29 with Synaptic
It just returns `E: Internal Error, No file name for sgml-base:amd64`

Successfully ran:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade

root@Bionic-Beaver:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up sgml-base (1.29) ...
cannot rename /var/lib/sgml-base/supercatalog to /var/lib/sgml-base/supercatalog.old: Operation not permitted at /usr/sbin/update-catalog line 322.
dpkg: error processing package sgml-base (--configure):
 installed sgml-base package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of metacity-common:
 metacity-common depends on sgml-base (>= 1.28); however:
  Package sgml-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package metacity-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sgml-data:
 sgml-data depends on sgml-base (>= 1.28); however:
  Package sgml-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sgml-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 sgml-base
 metacity-common
 sgml-data
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove remove problematic file with

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/sgml-base/supercatalog
```

and then reinstall three packages:

```
sudo apt-get install sgml-data metacity-common sgml-base --reinstall
```

Comment: Thanks. That put me on the right track anyway. I couldn't remove that file, even as root. Don't know why. I removed the existing sgml-base package too, and even that didn't help. Then I booted from live image and mounted the drive from there, and still couldn't get rid of it. No idea why. I was finally able to rename the directory it was in. After that, I could install sgml-base and all its dependents from Synaptic without issue. Weird thing is I can't get rid of the old file. Maybe something corrupt in the file system. Will try running fsck from the live image tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: I still can't remove the old supercatalog. fsck didn't find any problems with the file system (ext4).  Anyway, thanks for your help, N0rbert. I'm going to ask another question about the supercatalog file and mark this answered.